# Convert std::vector<uint8_t> to packed std::vector<uint64_t>

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

I am looking for a way to efficiently and without UB convert a `std::vector<uint8_t>` to a `std::vector<uint64_t>` s.t each element in the `std::vector<uint64_t>` holds information from 8 elements from the `std::vector<uint8_t>`. The remainder elements should be filled with zeros but that can be done later.

The best approach I've come up with so far is:

```
std::vector<uint64_t> foo(std::vector<uint8_t> const & v8) {
    std::vector<uint64_t> v64;
    v64.reserve((v8.size() + 7) / 8);
    size_t i = 0;
    uint64_t tmp;
    for(; i + 8 < v8.size(); i += 8) {
        memcpy(&tmp, v8.data() + i, 8);
        v64.push_back(tmp);
    }
    tmp = 0; // fill remainder with 0s.
    memcpy(&tmp, v8.data() + i, v8.size() - i);
    v64.push_back(tmp);
    return v64;
}
```

But I'm hoping there is some cleaner / better approach.

Edit1: The solution about misses byte-order concerns. Pointed out by @VainMain.

Could be fixed with a byte-swap after the `memcpy`.

Comment: You may want to know endianness: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness.

Comment: @VainMan does it matter here? Im essentially trying to reinterpret a byte array at uint64_t array with the exact same byte pattern. Or are you saying it would be an issue for any standard solution?

Comment: Yes. What would you expecting when a two-byte array of `{1, 2}` is converted to `uint16_t`？ `(1 << 8) | 2` or `(2 << 8) | 1`？

Comment: @VainMan fair. I it matter if you need to use the uint64_t as an actual integer which is probably expectation so guess it needs a byte swap. But exact same byte pattern is essentially endian independent.

Comment: Yes. I should have(but I haven't, my bad) pointed out the problem is what you're going to do with the converted result, without converting back to byte array properly. I think that operations on the result, except non-shifting/trailing/leading-like bitwise operations, will involve endianness issue.

Comment: If all you want is the "byte pattern" you said, I think `memcpy(v64.data(), v8.data(), v8.size())`  is ok, but I'm not very sure.

Comment: @VainMan Originally I had that with an earlier `v64.resize()` but that essentially wastes a `memset` which can be significant if the vector is large. But for the actual question you are certainly right about missing the endianness, not going to change my question to a niche-use case, a 'proper' way to do this is still the goal.

Comment: `vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, ...)`, would this ctor save from `memset`-ing `std::vector<uint64_t> v64` at initialisation ? Iterators basically a pointer if you explicitly cast pointer from `uint8_t` to `uint64_t` for this ctor (putting endianness aside and assuming that uint8_t vector has divided by 8 elements).

Comment: @user3124812 yeah but that would violate strict aliasing AFAIK.

Comment: And potentially fail altogether if the input isn't aligned.  `memcpy` solves both problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you are up to using the [range-v3 library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you can use `ranges::view::chunk` (or the probably [soon available C++23 standard library implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23) equivalent).

This will especially relieve you from calculating the required size of the vector to store the packed values in:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

std::vector<std::uint64_t> pack(const std::span<const std::uint8_t> values)
{
    const auto chunked_view = ranges::view::chunk(values, 8);

    std::vector<std::uint64_t> packed(ranges::size(chunked_view));
    ranges::transform(chunked_view, packed.begin(), [](const auto& word) {

        std::array<std::uint8_t, 8> buf{0}; // init with all 0's
        ranges::copy(word, buf.begin());

        std::uint64_t packed_word;
        std::memcpy(&packed_word, buf.data(), 8);
        return packed_word;
    });
    
    return packed;
}
```

Example ([see on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/nharx3s4n))

```
int main()
{
    std::array<uint8_t, 9> values;
    std::iota(values.begin(), values.end(), std::uint8_t{0});

    for (auto t : pack(values))
        std::cout << std::hex << t << std::endl;
    // prints
    // 706050403020100
    // 8
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why copy from the span into an array then into memcpy? To handle a length not divisible by 8? I would reject inputs like that

Comment: @Caleth Yes, that's exactly the reason ("The remainder elements should be filled with zeros [but that can be done later]"). Without the array one would need to copy directly via memcpy from `word` (which is then required to be a contiguous range) or `packed_word` would need to be reinterpret_casted into `std::uint8_t*` to pass it to `memcpy`. When choosing the latter method, the gcc binary does not [change at all compared to the version with the array](https://godbolt.org/z/KMxx8oK3x).